# LeanFT not able to find windows or screen when running from command prompt - Terminal Emulator IBM Application

Tags: java, maven, cucumber, leanft

Am running automation on terminal emulator IBM PCOMM application, framework consists , maven + leanft +cucumber+ java + junit , when i run the feature from runner file , i am able to execute the tests , but when i using maven command through command prompt , it is opening the application but not able to type anything

**maven command:**

```
mvn clean  verify -Dcucumber.filter.tags="@Mainframe"
```

**below is the command used for launch :**

```
        ModifiableSDKConfiguration sdkConfig = new ModifiableSDKConfiguration();
        sdkConfig.setServerAddress(new URI("ws://localhost:5095"));
        SDK.init(sdkConfig);
        File file = new File(filePath);
            java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop().open(file);
```

**to insert text :**

```
screen.describe(Field.class,
            new FieldDescription.Builder().startPosition(row, col).isProtected(false).visible(true).build())
            .setText(text);
screen.sync();
```

**Leanft version : 14.53**

**Screen logic:**

```
Window teWindow = Desktop.describe(Window.class, new WindowDescription.Builder().shortName(new RegExpProperty(".*")).build()); 
Screen screen = teWindow.describe(Screen.class, new ScreenDescription.Builder().label(new RegExpProperty(".*")).build());
```

**Error:**

```
com.hp.lft.sdk.ReplayObjectNotFoundException: Cannot find the "Terminal Emulators Field" object's parent "Terminal Emulators Window" (class TeWindow). Verify that parent properties match an object currently displayed in your application.
```

**If i try opening application with LeanFT Terminal Emulator Technology , am getting below error :**

```
com.hp.lft.sdk.GeneralLeanFtException: spawn UNKNOWN
    at com.hp.lft.sdk.internal.GeneralExceptionFactory.createDefault(GeneralExceptionFactory.java:154)
    at com.hp.lft.sdk.internal.GeneralExceptionFactory.createDefault(GeneralExceptionFactory.java:8)
    at com.hp.lft.sdk.internal.CommunicationClientImpl.handleError(CommunicationClientImpl.java:224)
    at com.hp.lft.sdk.internal.CommunicationClientImpl.send(CommunicationClientImpl.java:96)
    at com.hp.lft.sdk.internal.AutLaunchHelper$1.invoke(AutLaunchHelper.java:80)
    at com.hp.lft.sdk.internal.AutLaunchHelper$1.invoke(AutLaunchHelper.java:61)
    at com.hp.lft.sdk.internal.TestObjectOperationWrapper.executeWithEvents(TestObjectOperationWrapper.java:120)
```

Comment: and what is the error thrown? also, do you really need to set a server address manually?

Comment: Hi @Adelin , this is the error am getting : com.hp.lft.sdk.ReplayObjectNotFoundException: Cannot find the "Terminal Emulators Field" object's parent "Terminal Emulators Window" (class TeWindow).
Verify that parent properties match an object currently displayed in your application.

Comment: And yes even don't set the address , i am getting another error , com.hp.lft.sdk.GeneralLeanFtException: An Internal problem has occurred, please make sure the LeanFT sdk was properly initialized.
 at com.hp.lft.sdk.internal.CommunicationClientImpl.send(CommunicationClientImpl.java:72)

Comment: @Adelin : any suggestion here ?

Comment: what is `screen`? and it looks like java awt is used to launch the app instead of TE technology. Is the TE enabled in the engine settings?

Comment: Yes  , i enabled TE , i made screen as generic  , "Window teWindow = Desktop.describe(Window.class,
    new WindowDescription.Builder().shortName(new RegExpProperty(".*")).build());
  Screen screen = teWindow.describe(Screen.class,
    new ScreenDescription.Builder().label(new RegExpProperty(".*")).build());
  screen.sendTEKeys(Keys.ENTER);
  screen.sync();"

Comment: can you help launch the application with TE technology ? snippet please ?

Comment: com.hp.lft.sdk.GeneralLeanFtException: AUT launch is not allowed. Verify that the AUT is configured in autConfig.json. fileName=C:/ProgramData/IBM/Personal Communications/TN3270.WS, args=[undefined], workingDirectory=undefined

Comment: {
    "allowedAuts": [
        {
            "fileName": "C:\\ProgramData\\IBM\\Personal Communications\\TN3270.WS"
        }
    ]
}

Comment: @Adelin : Can you help me on this please ?

Comment: please edit the question to add the details I asked for. Comments are terrible to read. Use markdown to highlight code

Comment: @Adelin: Done ! Please let me know if you need any other info.

Comment: did you follow these steps? https://admhelp.microfocus.com/uftdev/en/14.50-14.53/HelpCenter/Content/HowTo/TE_Addin_Overview.htm

Comment: Run <LeanFT Installation>\bin\TeConfigurator.exe. , except this step , i made sure engine is up and running , added Addin for terminal emulator , as i said am able to run with eclipse with JWT Desktop , only problem is when running through maven command from command prompt. Do you think java is causing this issue ? i See , lean FT java is getting initialized when running from eclipse.

Comment: Run <LeanFT Installation>\bin\TeConfigurator.exe i couldn't find this exe file , my leanFT got installed with UFT package.